# How to click on the element on a webpage as per the HTML using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have been trying for a while now but can't seem to find this element using python selenium. All methods I used whether they were find with xpath, css selector, and or class came back negative so does anybody know how to find and click the element in the middle that has the value "LOG IN" and the type "button"?

```
<div id="62b00cbb-fb56-4b15-80bb-a8f965d02d90" class="nike-unite-submit-button loginSubmit nike-unite-component blurred">
 <input id="019a8673-60aa-4b9f-825a-00b01ad36507" type="button" value="LOG IN"> # Click This
</div>
```

I just can't seem to find it so any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

```
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=firefox_options)
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/launch/?cp=usns_aff_nike&s=upcoming')
time.sleep(.2)
logIn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > div.main-       layout > div > header > div.d-sm-h.d-lg-b > section > ul > li.member-nav-item.d-sm-ib.va-sm-m > button')
logIn.click()
time.sleep(.2)
email = driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress')
email.send_keys('email')
passWord = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passWord.send_keys('password')

# Find and click element from above
```

Everything else works fine its just when it comes to the select login button. Here is the code just in case their could be something wrong with it or somebody wanted to check it out, thanks

Comment: Show us exactly what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **LOG IN** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.nike-unite-submit-button.loginSubmit.nike-unite-component.blurred > input[value='LOG IN']"))).click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='nike-unite-submit-button loginSubmit nike-unite-component blurred']/input[@value='LOG IN']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: It's coming back with errors for both. When you click log in a pop up appears so maybe the pop up isn't part of the driver? I don't know why it wont find the login button but yet can find the password and email input

Comment: Check out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I added it and it seems that the element doesn't become clickable. The log in window just stays up waiting not clicking submit until it returns this error                                              selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @JohnDeBritto Update the question with a bit more of the relevant HTML and ensure that the elements are not within an iframe.

Comment: It's ok I searched and found a log in script on github and found the element find I was looking for: driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="nike-unite-loginForm"]/div[6]/input""").click().        Thank you though you were very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can find the button by using the ID of the button and then click it:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('019a8673-60aa-4b9f-825a-00b01ad36507')
button.click()
```

Here, driver is your browser webdriver.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="019a8673-60aa-4b9f-825a-00b01ad36507"]               This error pops up when I run it

Comment: It seems it can't find it using id but it can find the password and email address input. Maybe since its a popup its not part of the driver object?